# Team building for help desk representatives

Tags: management, team, leadership, teamwork, team-building

I'm trying to figure out how to organize a team building event for help desk representatives. The team has seven employees and i'm their manager. It's going to be more  of a relaxing afternoon (during business hours) away from work, go to a movie then grab dinner type of activity.

However, the nature of the work is that we must have someone manning the phones at all times. I thought about splitting the team and doing two outings. But that opens the door for personal cliques and how wants to go out with that person and not the other person, etc.

I was wondering if anybody had any ideas in that regard.

Comment: Can you forward calls to a company mobile. Let one or two people on location man the phones (not ideal, but maybe it would work for one day).

Answer (score 1):

First can someone from a different part of the organization man the phones for one afternoon? Can you or the other managers? If not, then what is really the nature of this event?

A movie isn't a team building event as you aren't even talking to each other. So if this is just a reward for good work, what is the harm if you offer two dates and they sign up for slots in them?

If you really want to get particular people to work better together, then you choose who goes to which event and choose the teams carefully with an eye for breaking up cliques. And choose something where people will be interacting with each other like bowling or mini-golf rather than a movie.